# How long should a chapter be? Can it be too short or too long?

Tags: creative-writing

My first chapter in my novel is only ten pages is that too short? Can a chapter even be too short or is it in the eye of the beholder?

Comment: I have recently asked the same question (https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36349/sizing-of-a-chapter-and-how-many-should-i-use). I have seen chapters of just a single word! And also seen stories without any chapters at all. I would say the sizing needs to feel natural.

Comment: As a teacher of mine once answered the class on an essay length (and this was intended for teenage boys, so forgive the crassness), writing anything is like a girl's skirt:  It should be long enough to cover everything, but short enough to keep it interesting.